# $E$ is a real Hilbert space of infinite-dimensional.

Tags: hilbert-spaces

If $E$ is a real Hilbert space of infinite dimension, why is $GL(E)$  connected in $L(E)$?

Comment: Are you certain this is true? It false for finite-dimensional real vector spaces...

Comment: yes it is false for finite-dimensional real vector spaces. For many Banach spaces,the group of invertible operators $GL(E)$ is connected. This is the case, for all Hilbert spaces. I need to know why it is true if $E$ is a real Hilbert spaces.

Comment: "This is the case, for all Hilbert spaces." ??? if you know this you're done...